# API for Telegram Bot that check if there is any online user or not

Tags: telegram-bot

I want to make a function in my Telegram Bot using python that returns a boolean value, "false" when no one is online and "true" when someone is online. But I couldn't find any related API. would you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bot API has no access to the online status of users. For the full list of methods available in the Bot API please see [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).